# Add custom functions/methods to test controller t

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, testcafe, web-testing

Is there way to add custom methods to test controller 't'. For e.g like

```
await t.click('some selector').CustomMethod('some selector')
```

I am looking to write tests using page object model, and I need to reuse a custom helper method repeatedly on multiple pages/occasions. But the way I have to use it now seems clunky.

```
await t.click(pagemodel.field1);
await DoTask('Task1');      // reusable helper method
await t.click(pagemodel.field2);
await DoTask('Task2');      // reusable helper method
```

what I think could be more natural/reasonable is

```
await t
   .click(pagemodel.field1).DoTask('Task1')
   .click(pagemodel.field2).DoTask('Task2');
```

Or perhaps there is a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, TestCafe does not support the described functionality.

It's difficult to recommend anything without knowing your full scenario.

Probably, you can put some methods directly into your `pagemodel` as done in the [Add Actions to the Page Model](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/recipes/extract-reusable-test-code/use-page-model.html#step-7---add-actions-to-the-page-model) article.

In addition, you can take a look at the [Extending Selectors](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/extending-selectors.html) article

Comment: The issue I see with adding methods to Page Model is that I have 15 fields on the page I would have to create 15 separate methods for them, just because they have different parameter values, I am looking to avoid any repetition of code. Extending Selectors also appears another way to create these methods for all the fields. As you can see, I am able to achieve what I want, but I think there is a better way to do this for code maintenance

Comment: I suggest you track a similar issue on GitHub: [Provide the capability to add custom actions to the test controller](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/1535)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create a page object, add a

```
function doSomething(field, task) {
    await t.click(field);
    await DoTask(task);      // reusable helper method 
}
```

and then

```
pageObject.doSomething(pagemodel.field1, 'Task1');
pageObject.doSomething(pagemodel.field2, 'Task2');
```